# Ruby Gems or just place the source code in vendor/assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

There's 2 main ways to include JS libraries in a Ruby on Rails 3.2.x project:

1. Put the files in vendor/assets
2. Use the ruby gems in bundler, such as:
   gem 'rails-backbone'
   gem 'jquery-rails'

Are there reasons that either way is preferred? I suspect that #1 makes the files a bit more obvious in the project, and #2 is a bit more convenient. I definitely do not want minified versions in the project or gems, as that makes debugging and reading the js source code unreasonable.

Comment: I prefer the bundler way as it is lot cleaner, and there are mechanisms like http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html in rails3.1 onwards too. For debugging, #1 is a good idea, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "vendor/assets" i have the opportunity to customize my jquery libs (e.g. for JqueryUI, or some jquery plugins etc.) But it is not trivial to deploy the libraries (e.g. because of assets pipeline). With gem solution you have no or little possibility to customize the libs, but no trouble with assets pipeline.